Disable security for integration tests Spring security 6
I am trying to disable security for integrations tests but nothing is working so far.
This is my pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.kaiho</groupId>
    <artifactId>diagnomanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>DiagnoManager</name>
    <description>Software de gestion asistencial domiciliaria y hospitalaria</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mapstruct.version>1.6.0.Beta1</mapstruct.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.11.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.30</org.projectlombok.version>

        <!-- JaCoCo Properties -->
        <jacoco.version>0.8.6</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
        <sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
        <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
        <sonar.language>java</sonar.language>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency> <!-- This dependency will help us start our docker-compose file when the application starts up.-->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-docker-compose</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        ...
    </build>

</project>

I am trying to test this rest controller:
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v1/patients", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class PatientRestController {

    private final PatientHandler patientHandler;

    @Operation(summary = "Creates a new patient")
    @PostMapping(consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('WRITE_PATIENTS')")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiGenericResponse<PatientResponseDto>> createPatient(@RequestBody @Valid ApiGenericRequest
            <PatientRequestDto> request) {
        PatientRequestDto data = request.getData();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(patientHandler.createPatient(data), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}

With this test class:
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
@ActiveProfiles("test-integration")
@Import({TestSecurityConfig.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test-integration.yaml")
class PatientRestControllerTest {

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:latest");

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private PatientEntityRepository patientEntityRepository;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        patientEntityRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void clearContext() {
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
    }
    @Test
     void shouldCreatePatientAndReturnCreatedStatus() throws Exception {
        // given
        MetaRequest meta = new MetaRequest();
        PatientRequestDto data = new PatientRequestDto(IdType.CC, "987654321", "XXX",
                "YYY", "ZZZ", "AAA",
                LocalDate.of(1993, 5, 18), Gender.FEMALE, BloodType.Aneg, MaritalStatus.SINGLE,
                "123456789", "test@gmail.com", "05", "005", Zone.URBAN,
                "Random Address", "57", "asdf",
                "BBB", "CCC", "1234567");
        ApiGenericRequest<PatientRequestDto> request = new ApiGenericRequest<>(meta, data);

        // when
        ResultActions perform = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/patients")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(request))
        );

        // then
        perform.andExpect(status().isCreated());

        assertThat(patientEntityRepository.findAll()).hasSize(1);
    }
}

I have tried different things but none of them has worked:
I have my SecurityConfig and TestSecurityConfig
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers(
                                "/actuator/prometheus",
                                "/api/v1/auth/**",
                                "/api/v1/patients/**").permitAll()
                                .requestMatchers("/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()

                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        return http.build();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Profile("test-integration")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = false)
public class TestSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .anyRequest().permitAll()
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().anyRequest();
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodSecurityExpressionHandler methodSecurityExpressionHandler() {
        DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler expressionHandler = new DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
        expressionHandler.setPermissionEvaluator(new DenyAllPermissionEvaluator());
        return expressionHandler;
    }

    private static class DenyAllPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {
        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType, Object permission) {
            return true;
        }
}

Also tried this on @BeforeEach:
@BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        patientEntityRepository.deleteAll();
        SecurityContext securityContext = Mockito.mock(SecurityContext.class);
        Authentication authentication = Mockito.mock(Authentication.class);

        Mockito.when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
        Mockito.when(authentication.isAuthenticated()).thenReturn(true);
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
        System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
    }

And also tried @WebMvcTest(PatientRestController.class) instead of @SpringBootTest and @MockBean in the necessary dependencies but this approach would make me mock the result of the operation in the database, which according to me, would be against testcontainers approach.
The error that I am getting is this one:
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Request processing failed: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied


Caused by: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.attemptAuthorization(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:256)
    at org.springframework.security.authorization.method.AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuthorizationManagerBeforeMethodInterceptor.java:197)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:751)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703)
    at com.kaiho.diagnomanager.infrastructure.patient.input.rest.PatientRestController$$SpringCGLIB$$0.createPatient(<generated>)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at ...

In my application.yaml I have this:
spring:
  application:
    name: diagnomanager

  sql:
    init:
      mode: always

  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true

logging:
  level:
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: DEBUG
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: TRACE

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: test-integration

  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE

And in my application-test-integration.yaml I have this:
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  autoconfigure:
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE
security:
  ignored: /**

